# is there an Accurev CLI command for deep overlapped files specifically?

Tags: version-control, accurev

Im looking for a command that gives me all the deep overlapped files in a stream.

I've tried

```
accurev stat -B *.cs
```

Doesn't really work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

accurev stat -B -o *.cs

Answer (score 3):

You should pass in the stream name where you want to search for deep overlaps as well as the -o switch for overlaps.

Example:  accurev stat -s stream_name_to_search_in -o -B

Comment: And yes, as anonymous says, if you are in a workspace issuing the command, "accurev stat -o -B *.cs" will work fine without having to specify a search stream...